# Why does the Informix 4GL compiler complain about unknown option -fwritable-strings?

Tags: informix, 4gl

I am beginner at Informix and when I want to compile and debug a program in Informix 4GL, but I can't.

This the code:

```
MAIN 
   DISPLAY "HELLO"
END MAIN
```

And this the problem:

```
cc:errors: option "-fwritable-strings" non reconnue sur la ligne de commande, aviez-vous l'intention d'utiliser "-writ-string" 4GL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `c4gl` script is setting the GCC command option `-fwritable-strings` but your C compiler (apparently `cc`, but it could be a link to GCC) doesn't recognize it.

Depending on whether you have GCC or not, there are different ways to fix it.  GCC 5.x (confirmed with GCC 5.3.0) and later does not support the option.  Linux has been stuck on GCC 4.x for a long time, but is finally moving forward to later versions of GCC.  So, if you've using GCC 5.x or later (use `cc --version` or `gcc --version` to find out which version you're using), you will need to edit the `c4gl` script (after making a backup copy of it) to remove the option.

However, there's also a chance that it was crucial and the code in the I4GL library does end up trying to modify string literals sometimes, and that will cause the program to crash.  At that point, you're stuck with trying to report a problem to IBM Informix (HCL) technical support, assuming you have support, or with downgrading to a version 4.x GCC compiler.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but when I edit c4gl I find others problems. One of these problems is change libstdc++-8.3.1 to libstdc++-3.2-1.i386.rpm.
But thus version cannot install because the redHat 7 install by default the version libstdc++-8.3.1 and I can't remove it.

Comment: I was a bit afraid that this might be the surface of the trouble.  If the code won't work on RHEL 7.x, that's something that Informix (IBM, HCL) needs to know — indeed, I'll discuss it with my management, but customer confirmation also helps.

Comment: This is the script which I want to compile:
MAIN 
DISPLAY "hello"
END MAIN 

It Is a simple script.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I recognize "hello world" in I4GL.  The problem is that the version of I4GL you're trying to use is not working on the platform you're trying to use it on.  It's possible that you've not got the latest version of I4GL — which version are you using?  It's also possible that the latest version of I4GOL for RHEL was produced for an older version of RHEL and is simply not compatible with the version you're using.  Can you provide version information please — I4GL 7.32.FCx (what's the x, and are there any other letters after it)?  And the version of RH you're using.

Comment: This all the version i use :
-RHEL :8.2 
-Informix dynamic server: 14.10 FC4W1 
-4GL : 7.32.UC2 

But I can't change the version because we have other application cannot work in the new version.

Comment: Thank you — that will help me.

Comment: I'm interested that you're using 7.32.UC2 — that's a 32-bit version of I4GL.  I'd expect there to be a 64-bit version such as 7.32.FCx.  But I'm not sure that would resolve the problem with the C++ library version.

Comment: I can't install 4GL version 64 bits 7.32.FCx(For me x is 4).
Error is :
cannot execute binary file : Exec format error

Comment: The 'exec format error' is odd — it normally means that the binary is completely the wrong format for the machine.  Do you have a support contract?  This is the sort of stuff that Tech Support normally deals with fairly fast.

Comment: I ask the support he says i need to do an update of the version

Comment: The number of this error is -4604, and I don't find it in the support of the codes errors

Comment: Looking at a product life-cycle chart (https://www.cursor-distribution.de/en/ibm-software/support-informix/informix-lifecycle-tab-en), the current version of I4GL is 7.51, not 7.32.  My brain is rusting.  7.32 was probably ported to RHEL4 or thereabouts.  Anyway, you need to upgrade to I4GL version 7.51 (since 7.50 is also out of support).

Comment: Hello Jonathan, yeah, I know this but the we can't upgrade the version because we have other application not compatible for the new version.

Comment: Now I change the version of the red hat to 7.9 and the compilator to 4.8 and when I want to compile also don't work
Error : 
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fwritable-strings’

Comment: The `-fwritable-strings` option was removed from GCC a while ago.  Your setup is no longer usable — you either have to retrench to the versions you had before you started the upgrade process or you have to upgrade I4GL.

Comment: So the solution is the update of the version to the new version.
We don't have other solution.

Comment: You're stuck between a rock and a hard place.  Nominally, one option is to go back to the setup that was working for the last 15 years or so and continue using it.  You won't then have any problems because of changes, but you have 15 years accumulated risk.  Another option is to go with a supported and supportable configuration of I4GL, rebuilding what needs rebuilding.  However, if there is code that is proven to work in I4GL 7.32 but proven to fail with 7.51, then (a) you'll need to identify what causes the failure and (b) you are in an unhappy situation.

Comment: In general, I4GL 7.32 and I4GL 7.51 should work the same.  If there's a problem, it may be readily identifiable, possibly with a known fix.  But those problems should be arcane and may involve C code interfaces needing an update.  But without information, it's hard to be sure.